# apt purge nginx return failure

Tags: nginx, service, systemctl

× nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-10-13 19:40:27 +0330; 4ms ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 115336 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 2ms

Oct 13 19:40:27 local-server2 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 13 19:40:27 local-server2 nginx[115336]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/mime.types" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:18
Oct 13 19:40:27 local-server2 nginx[115336]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Oct 13 19:40:27 local-server2 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 13 19:40:27 local-server2 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 13 19:40:27 local-server2 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
installed nginx-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
nginx-core
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

i want to purge and fully delete enginx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.